# Quickly create 3 ruby objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create 3 objects in a loop like this...

```
3.times do |i|
  @part + i.to_s = Part.create(part_number: "000#{i + 1}")
end
```

I get the error

> NoMethodError: undefined method to_s=' for 0:Fixnum`

I think its obvious what I am trying to do? I'd like three parts (`@part1`/`@part2`/`@part3`) with part numbers 0001/2/3 after the loop runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Roman already suggested, you should use an array.

However, to answer you question:

```
3.times do |i|
  instance_variable_set("@part#{i + 1}", Part.create(part_number: "000#{i + 1}"))
end
```

Or even:

```
(1..3).each do |i|
  instance_variable_set("@part#{i}", Part.create(part_number: "000#{i}"))
end
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks Chris. I did not know about instance_variable_set method.